# Netfilter kernel module to intercept packets and log them

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, netfilter

I had a basic code. This code drops and logs all the incoming and outgoing packets.
I want to write a netfilter kernel module to intercept packets and log them in the kernel logs. It should be able to detect different(show 1 or 2 as example) kinds of TCP based reconnaissance packets. The module should detect these packets and log to kernel logs. I don't want to filter the packets, just identify and log them.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;         //struct holding set of hook function options

//function to be called by hook
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff **skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "packet dropped\n");                                             //log to var/log/messages
  return NF_DROP;                                                                   //drops the packet
}

//Called when module loaded using 'insmod'
int init_module()
{
  nfho.hook = hook_func;                       //function to call when conditions below met
  nfho.hooknum = NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING;            //called right after packet recieved, first hook in Netfilter
  nfho.pf = PF_INET;                           //IPV4 packets
  nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;             //set to highest priority over all other hook functions
  nf_register_hook(&nfho);                     //register hook

  return 0;                                    //return 0 for success
}

//Called when module unloaded using 'rmmod'
void cleanup_module()
{
  nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);                     //cleanup – unregister hook
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First, this module drops only incoming packets. The reason is the following row: `nfho.hooknum = NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING;`. 
About your question: I don't understand what are "based reconnaissance packets", but you can extract all the data from the packet and show them in kernel logs. For example:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;         //struct holding set of hook function options

//function to be called by hook
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
  struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb); //you can access to IP source and dest - ip_header->saddr, ip_header->daddr
  struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
  if (ip_header->protocol == 6) //TCP protocol
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "TCP Packet\n");
    tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)(skb_transport_header(skb)+20); //Note: +20 is only for incoming packets
    printk(KERN_INFO "Source Port: %u\n", tcp_header->source); //can access dest in the same way
  }
  return NF_ACCEPT;                                                                   //accept the packet
}

//Called when module loaded using 'insmod'
int init_module()
{
  nfho.hook = hook_func;                       //function to call when conditions below met
  nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;            //called right after packet recieved, first hook in Netfilter
  nfho.pf = PF_INET;                           //IPV4 packets
  nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;             //set to highest priority over all other hook functions
  nf_register_hook(&nfho);                     //register hook

  return 0;                                    //return 0 for success
}

//Called when module unloaded using 'rmmod'
void cleanup_module()
{
  nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);                     //cleanup – unregister hook
}
```

Comment: @MukeshGupta N.B.: It makes sense to **check the return value** of `nf_register_hook()`, because it can lead to unregistering nonexistent hook while unloading (there will be warning stack traces in `dmesg`). Also there are some more handy functions like [`ip_hdr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.206/source/include/linux/ip.h#L23) and [`tcp_hdr`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.206/source/include/linux/tcp.h#L27).

Answer (score -1):

You could simply run the `ufw` firewall utility,

(which you should be running all the time anyway).

start it with:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

then to assure it is running :

```
sudo ufw status
```

then turn the logging function on :

```
sudo ufw logging on
```

then :

```
cd /var/log
```

then to view the log :

```
sudo cat ufw.log
```

This will give a log of everything that is input/output.

Comment: that worked, but I want to create a kernel module for that. just for learning. How can I do that ?

Comment: Some one else will need to answer the question about how to  create the kernel module.   That's an area I'm not very familiar with.

Comment: Seems you'd want something like http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/netfilter/xt_LOG.c?v=3.10